# Can't type ] or } in either the Terminal or Emacs while in "Español - ISO" keyboard language mode

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal, emacs

I can type `[` and `{` with no issues, but when I type `]` nothing happens, and when I type `}` a `?` sign is typed instead. This is an issue only while in Terminal or Emacs (Terminal and GUI).

Everything works fine while in UnitedStates keyboard language mode. This problem is exclusive to  `Español - ISO` and `Español` kayboard language mode.

This is my keyboard:
[image: My Keyboard]

The `]` sign is in `alt` + `+`. The `}` sign is in `alt` + `ç`. These are the ones that are not working.

What can I do to fix this? I need them to work in `Español - ISO` or `Español` kayboard language mode.

Comment: When I tried using the "Spanish - ISO" input method in Terminal, I couldn't type `|`, `@`, or `#` either.

Comment: Have you looked into using the key translation map?

Comment: How about something simple like this?:  `(global-set-key (kbd "M-v") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "✓")))`  You can use it to insert anything.  `YASnippet` is a package that could also be used to insert something.

Answer (score 2):

Dunno whether this helps, but there are lots of google hits for this and similar questions. Here is [one answer](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/992603?start=0&tstart=0), which might help if you are on an Apple computer:

```
OK, then open the International preference of System Preferences.
Click on the Input Menu tab (rightmost tab.) Check the box to display the Keyboard
Viewer.  You should now have a menu bar item for the Keyboard Viewer. When you
select, it should open the viewer so you can find the location of the keys for the
brackets.
```

[Another answer](http://infopython.wordpress.com/2007/09/03/macbook-keyboard-write-box-or-square-brackets/) for a Mac says to use `Alt+Shift+)` for `]`. Dunno whether that will help you.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

[Emacs auto-pair](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoPairs) might be what you're looking for.  It's specific to your need.

Answer (score 1):

well, I had the same problem using iTerm.. what solved for me was going to preferences > profiles > keys then selecting "normal" on "left option keys acts as" field (also did for right option key). its default was to act as +Esc so whenever i typed it it was sending esc+] signal.

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard you look at, the one in front of you, have the characters located in a different place than the Español keyboard. That's why looking at the keyboard viewer will give you an easier way to use the keyboard (which physically displays symbols for an English only Keyboard) and locate where those keys are when in Español. 
   I use a different method for writing. I keep the English keyboard and use ASCII to enter Español differences, which I mostly know by memory now, Like ñ which shows when pressing ALT + 164. And í =ALT + 161, ó = ALT + 162, ú = ALT + 163, á = ALT + 160 and é = ALT + 160. You can do a google search to download ASCII and keep the English keyboard. A lot easier. Unless you are looking to reconfigure the Español keyboard in a new system. In which case you can create any script for your needs.